# I accidentally cloned my 16GB SD card to my 256 GB pendrive using dd. Is there any way to retrieve back my pendrive?

Tags: data-recovery, dd, partition-recovery, file-recovery, testdisk

I have a 16GB SD card, which when I connect to my computer, gives cant read superblock error (in Ubuntu). After searching on internet, I saw some solutions using testdisk tool and decided to try it out. In one example it mentioned to backup my drive, so I did:

```
dd if=/(location of sd card) of=/(my pendrive location) status=progress
```

I gave:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc status=progress
```

,which I realised as a blunder only after it wrote about 100MB into my pendrive. I suddenly cancelled my operation (Ctrl C) and then rebooted to check if my pendrive was damaged. Now the Pendrive name is changed to my sd card name and storage (that I checked in Windows Disk manager option) is showing only 14.56GB instead of 256 GB and 218.31 GB unallocated.

I tried testdisk on Ubuntu, and luckily in that it is showing my pendrive's original name and size, but when I listed the contents using the same tool, it is showing my SD card's contents only (which I saw when I used testdisk with SD card)
Is there anyway with which I can recover both devices, or at least my 256 GB pendrive please?
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Your data is gone, but what does `lsblk` on Linux show about the pendrive? Total storage capacity is not something that can be transferred through 'dd', only the partition table is.

Comment: Hi, lsblk shows the same as what was shown by wndows disk manager. lsblk shows sdc as 232.9G (Disk) and sdc1 as 14.6G (Part). Can I retrieve my data from the 256 gb pendrive by myself using testdisk/similar software or should I contact a recovery service?  Thanks!

Comment: 1. Recover data from the 256 GB drive, though since *you interrupted the process*, likely there *isn't* any.  2. Open the flash drive in Windows using *diskmgmt.msc* or *DiskGenius*, or in Ubuntu using GNOME *Disks* application, create one 256 GB partition and format it, probably as FAT32, though exFAT might work if you have fuse installed in Ubuntu. Any data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I've done:
I used testdisk and played with all the options like copying backup boot sector over original, rebuild boot sector etc.. all the options that seemed suitable. I even tried repair FAT option. Anyways the sd card is usable now; I don't exactly know which option worked out.

Regarding pendrive: I deleted the 16GB partition of the 256 GB pendrive using windows disk manager.
Then I tried an old version of Easeus recovery pro (some vers 5.1) as shown in a youtube videa, and I recovered the files. But many photos were destroyed in the final result. I am not sure whether the photos have been destroyed during the formatting or while recovery. Then I used PhotoRec by testdisk on the same drive, which recovered only the non-corrupted files, I understood that I lost some 3k photos.
I wrote a simple python script to sort all these recovered images as per its resolution to either screenshots or my camera photos or whatsapp/downloads trash photos.